# How to select and style the active NavLink element with React Router DOM and SCSS?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, sass, react-router, css-selectors

I'm currently working on a React project with TypeScript and using SCSS for styling. I'm trying to select and style the active NavLink element from react-router-dom but haven't been successful. Below is the relevant code:

**Menu Component (JSX):**

```
const Menu: FC<MenuProps> = () => {
  return(
  <div className={styles.Menu}>
    <NavLink to={"/profile"} >
      <div className={styles.navItem}>
        <FaHouseUser />
        <p>Profile</p>
      </div>
    </NavLink>
    <hr />
    
    <NavLink to={"/favorites"} >
      <div className={styles.navItem}>
        <FaRegHeart />
        <p>Favorites</p>
      </div>
    </NavLink>
    <hr />

    <NavLink to={"/explore"} >
      <div className={styles.navItem}>
        <FaSearch />
        <p>Explore</p>
      </div>
    </NavLink>
    <hr />

    <NavLink to={"/home"} >
      <div className={styles.navItem}>
        <FaHome />
        <p>Home</p>
      </div>
    </NavLink>
  </div>
  )
}
```

**SCSS Styling:**

```
  & > a {
    width: 25%;
    height: 100%;

    & > .navItem {
      @extend %flexCol;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: center;
      gap: 0.25em;

      & > svg {
        color: rgba($colorPrimary, 0.75);
        font-size: 1.5em;
      }

      & > p {
        color: rgba($colorPrimary, 1);
        font-size: 0.75em;
      }
    }
  }
```

I am using ReactJS with TypeScript and SCSS for styling. I haven't been able to select the "active" NavLink element. There are no error messages or console logs related to this problem, and I have checked for potential interference from other dependencies in my project.

i see that class does displayed in the element from the devtools but still i cant style it...

How can I select and style the active NavLink element using React Router DOM and SCSS? Any guidance or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: *What* active styling/CSS are you wanting, or trying, to apply, and *where* are you trying to apply it? I'm not super familiar with SASS, but have you tried a selector with the `& > a` and `.active` class the `NavLink` provides?

Comment: hey, thankes for your answer.
i did try nesting them because in sass it modifes it while compiling so i cant reach the class i need...

Comment: What are you nesting? What is modified? It shouldn't be modifying the `"active"` classname the `NavLink` uses.

Comment: well, as far as i know sass modifies the classes to use its module so it adds a unique id to it which is complicating things a little bit if you want to catch elements like this...

Comment: Well, that can be worked around. Can you [edit] to clarify what specifically you are trying to style?

Answer (score 0):

I guess `:global(a.active) {}` will help you.

Comment: i tried it already, thanks

Answer (score 0):

If nothing else works, maybe you could try inline styling using router's isActive? (I'm fairly new at React and I've never worked with Typescript or SCSS)

```
<NavLink
  to="/profile"
  style={isActive => ({
    color: isActive ? "green" : "blue"
  })}
></NavLink>
```